# ZF2 Di Fatal Error after Update to 2.1.0

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

After updating my ZF2 Libary to the newest Version my Application is throwing a Fatal Error. In the prev. Version 1.0.6 all works fine. I was looking for the source of the error, but i cant find it and i have no clue. Maybe something is wrong with my DI Injection Array in the Module.Config. Hope someone have a idea what is going on here :)

When i remove my hole DI settings in the Module Config ... my Application wont work because the DI is not working but the fatal error disappears. :/

Fatal Error:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\Di\Exception\MissingPropertyException' with message 'Missing instance/object for parameter route for Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment::__construct' in ...\Zend\Di\Di.php:699

my DI Module Config:

```
    'di'                 => array(
        'definition' => array(
           'class' => array(
                'Application\View\Helper\LastActions'               => array(
                    'setBenutzerMapper' => array(
                        'required' => true
                    ),
                 ),
                 [...]
           )
         )
     ),
```

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

same issue is occurring to me. Im using SmartyModule from https://github.com/Domi-cc/SmartyModule. Its using 'di' on module.config.php but Im not seeing router configuration with long name

```
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'alias' => array(
            // entity manager
            'smarty_engine' => 'Smarty',
        ),

        'SmartyModule\View\Renderer\SmartyStrategy' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'smarty' => 'SmartyModule\View\Renderer\SmartyRenderer',
            ),
        ),
. . .
```

Comment: saw the fix here -- https://github.com/weierophinney/zf2/commit/5af3c125557025ac91e0952d0f2ac9aeb0600834  it solves my issue. Thanks @rb-cohen

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue for this over at github, I had the same problem this morning:
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/3625

The quickfix, until the patch makes it in to release, is to change your router configurations from using a long name like "Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment" to just "Segment", like this:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'restful' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            ...
```